# SWI-Prolog: Shortest path between multiple doubly-linked interconnected nodes

Tags: list, prolog, swi-prolog

I am trying to construct the shortest path between multiple nodes that are doubly connected. Like so:

```
A->B
B->A
A->C
C->A

A->D
D->A
D->X

X->Y
Y->X
X->Z
Z->X
```

They are also assigned costs to figure out the shortest path.
My issue here is that my prolog program always ends up going in circles when constructing a path from A->Z

Here is my code:

```
connected(a,b,10).
connected(b,a,10).
connected(a,c,10).
connected(c,a,10).
connected(a,d,10).
connected(d,a,10).

connected(d,x,20).

connected(x,y,10).
connected(y,x,10).
connected(z,x,10).
connected(x,z,10).

path(A,B,Path,C):-
    connected(A,B,C).

path(A,B,Path,C):-
    connected(X,B,C1),
    PathN = [X | Path],
    path(A,X,PathN,C2),
    C is C1+C2,
    Path = PathN.
```

Trace output of session:

```
  Redo: (18) path(a, b, [b, a, b, a, b, a, d, x|...], _10100) ? creep
   Call: (19) connected(_18442, b, _18444) ? creep
   Exit: (19) connected(a, b, 10) ? creep
   Call: (19) _19962=[a, b, a, b, a, b, a, d|...] ? creep
   Exit: (19) [a, b, a, b, a, b, a, d|...]=[a, b, a, b, a, b, a, d|...] ? creep
   Call: (19) path(a, a, [a, b, a, b, a, b, a, d|...], _21478) ? creep
   Call: (20) connected(a, a, _21478) ? creep
   Fail: (20) connected(a, a, _21478) ? creep
   Redo: (19) path(a, a, [a, b, a, b, a, b, a, d|...], _21478) ? creep
   Call: (20) connected(_24520, a, _24522) ? creep
   Exit: (20) connected(b, a, 10) ? creep
   Call: (20) _26040=[b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a|...] ? creep
   Exit: (20) [b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a|...]=[b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a|...] ? creep
   Call: (20) path(a, b, [b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a|...], _27556) ? creep
   Call: (21) connected(a, b, _27556) ? creep
   Exit: (21) connected(a, b, 10) ? creep
   Exit: (20) path(a, b, [b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a|...], 10) ? creep
   Call: (20) _21478 is 10+10 ? creep
   Exit: (20) 20 is 10+10 ? creep
   Call: (20) [a, b, a, b, a, b, a, d|...]=[b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a|...] ? creep
   Fail: (20) [a, b, a, b, a, b, a, d|...]=[b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a|...] ? creep
   Redo: (21) connected(a, b, _228) ? creep
   Fail: (21) connected(a, b, _228) ? creep
   Redo: (20) path(a, b, [b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a|...], _228) ? creep
   Call: (21) connected(_3680, b, _3682) ? creep
   Exit: (21) connected(a, b, 10) ? creep
   Call: (21) _5200=[a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b|...] ? creep
   Exit: (21) [a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b|...]=[a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b|...] ? creep
   Call: (21) path(a, a, [a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b|...], _6716) ? creep
   Call: (22) connected(a, a, _6716) ? creep
   Fail: (22) connected(a, a, _6716) ? creep
   Redo: (21) path(a, a, [a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b|...], _6716) ? creep
   Call: (22) connected(_9758, a, _9760) ? creep
   Exit: (22) connected(b, a, 10) ? creep
   Call: (22) _11278=[b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a|...] ? creep
   Exit: (22) [b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a|...]=[b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a|...] ? creep
   Call: (22) path(a, b, [b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a|...], _12794) ? creep
   Call: (23) connected(a, b, _12794) ? creep
   Exit: (23) connected(a, b, 10) ? creep
   Exit: (22) path(a, b, [b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a|...], 10) ? creep
   Call: (22) _6716 is 10+10 ? creep
   Exit: (22) 20 is 10+10 ? creep
   Call: (22) [a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b|...]=[b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a|...] ? creep
   Fail: (22) [a, b, a, b, a, b, a, b|...]=[b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a|...] ? creep
   Redo: (23) connected(a, b, _12794) ? creep
   Fail: (23) connected(a, b, _12794) ? creep
   Redo: (22) path(a, b, [b, a, b, a, b, a, b, a|...], _12794) ?
```

It ends up going back and forth between A->B and B->A. While technically I understand that this is within the set of all possible paths, its not what I intent.

My question is, how can I instruct prolog to not consider such paths? Or at least eliminate the infinite loop or limit/constrict it? If I limit the list to length 10 for example, I still get way too many permutations of A->B,B->A within a list of length 10.

Not homework. I am learning prolog on my own and wish to understand it properly.

Edit:
I managed to restrict it the way I wanted using `occurrences_of_term`, now I am just having some trouble getting a proper output list:

```
path(A,B,_,C,_):-
    connected(A,B,C).

path(A,B,L,C,Lout):-
    connected(X,B,C1),
    occurrences_of_term(X,L,Oc),
    (Oc < 2 -> 
        (
            path(A,X,[X|L],C2,Lout),
            C is C1+C2
        );
        (
            C is C1, Lout = L
        )
    ).
```

Output:

```
?- path(a,z,X,C,R)
|    .
C = 40 ;
C = 60 ;
C = 60,
R = [b, a, d, x|X] ;
C = 60 ;
C = 60,
R = [c, a, d, x|X] ;
C = 50,
R = [a, d, x|X] ;
C = 30,
R = [y, x|X] ;
C = 30,
R = [z, x|X].
```

Some help with cleaning up  the stray [x|X] would be appreciated.

Comment: To prevent visiting an already-visited position, use `\+ memberchk`, because `memberchk` is optimized in swi-prolog. Or start with `length`, to attempt ever-increasing lengths of paths. There's many Prolog path code examples, just a short Googling away...

Comment: @brebs I know but most of them dont deal with doubly-linked nodes. I am just learning and having trouble even finding stuff relating to prolog in the first place since its not used that often.

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution to the problem, hope you find interesting insights.

```
path(A, B, Path, VisitedNodes, C):-
    append([B], VisitedNodes, UpdatedNodes),
    connected(X, B, C1), 
    maplist(\=(X), VisitedNodes),  % X does not unify with any member of the list of Visited Nodes;
    (
        X= A, C is C1, 
        append([A, B], VisitedNodes, Path)
    ;
        path(A, X, Path, UpdatedNodes, C2),
        C is C1 + C2
    ).

find_path(StartNode, Dest):-
    path(StartNode, Dest, Path, [], Cost),
    atomic_list_concat(Path, ' -> ', PathDesc),
    atomic_list_concat(["Cost of the path:: ", Cost, "\nPath sequence: ", PathDesc, "\n"], AtomDesc),
    atom_string(AtomDesc, Desc), write(Desc).
```

Comment: Use `[Head|Tail]` notation, rather than `append`. Use `\+ memberchk` instead of `maplist`. For performance and elegance.